# Unity cannot cast SpriteRenderer to an interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an interface I use for components that can be faded (just requires `color` and `transform`).

```
public interface IFadeable
{
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public Transform transform { get; }
}
```

Both `SpriteRenderer` and `Image` should match this just fine. However, I can only cast Image but not the SpriteRenderer:

Example:

```
IFadeable image in go.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>() //Works fine
IFadeable sprite in go.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>() //Cast fails
```

Comment: "should match this just fine" yeah... but only if c# would not be statically typed...

Comment: And I should have a million dollars... oh wait, the world doesn't work that way, and neither does C#.

Comment: ... But i can give you a loaded gun so you can shoot your foot:  there is `dynamic` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast will pretty much fail in both cases.

Neither type actually implements that interface. This is not how `c#` works. Even if member names within two interfaces are identical - or in your case class members - if they are not within the same inheritance line then there is no relationship between them and you can't simply cast one to the other.

You can only cast something that

- actually **IS** of the target type - just potentially [(un)boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) or a parent/sub class type
- implements explicit or implicit conversions

You get a hard compiler error for `SpriteRenderer` but not for `Image` as `SpriteRenderer` is a [`sealed class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed) indicating that there are no further inheritors of this type. The compiler here can be 100% sure that there is definitely no situation where such an instance implements your custom interface.

For `Image` in theory you could inherit and implement your own

```
public class FadeableImage : Image, IFadeable { }
```

which actually would work since `Image` already has all the required members. However, the cast will of course only work on such instances of `Image` that in fact are actually `FadeableImage`.

Otherwise, on runtime you will just get an `InvalidCastException` for the `Image` as well. Since there is no type relation between `Image` and `IFadeable`.

---

You could of course have your own little wrapper around the situation

```
public class Fadeable : IFadeable
{
    public Color color 
    {
        get
        {
            return _type switch
            {
                Type.Image => _image.color,
                Type.SpriteRenderer => _spriteRenderer.color,
                _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
            };
        }

        set
        {
            switch (_type)
            {
                case Type.Image:
                    _image.color = value;
                    break;

                case Type.SpriteRenderer:
                    _spriteRenderer.color = value;
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    } 

    public Transform transform
    {
        get
        {
            return _type switch
            {
                Type.Image => _image.transform,
                Type.SpriteRenderer => _spriteRenderer.transform,
                _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
            };
        }
    }

    private Image _image;
    private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;

    private enum Type : byte
    {
        Image,
        SpriteRenderer
    }

    private Type _type;

    public Fadeable(Image image)
    {
        _image = image;
        _type = Type.Image;
    }

    public Fadeable(SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer)
    {
        _spriteRenderer = spriteRenderer;
        _type = Type.SpriteRenderer;
    }
}
```

and then e.g. use `Linq` and do

```
foreach(var fadeable in go.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>().Select(o => new Fadeable(o))
```

and accordingly

```
foreach(var fadeable in go.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().Select(o => new Fadeable(o))
```

of course you can do the same also without Linq

```
foreach(var image in go.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>())
{
    var fadeable = new Fadeable(image);
    ...
}

foreach(var spriteRenderer in go.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>())
{
    var fadeable = new Fadeable(spriteRenderer);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the insights, the wrapper is quite helpful